# How can I reorder levels of a list in a performant way?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

I have the following problem and I am not sure how to speed it up:

I construct a list element by element like so:

```
a[[i]]=Table[some_function[j,k],{j,1,3},{k,1,6}]
```

This results in a list `a` with three indices and I would like to reorder its indices as follows:

`Table[a[[i,j,k]],{j,1,3},{k,1,6},{i,1,4}]`

Notice that initially the first index in `a` was `i` and now it is moved to the last position.

What I do at the moment is traverse the list with `Table` and reorder it elements as above, but I am wondering if there is a faster way to do this.

If this was a simple matrix, the `Transpose` operation would do the trick but I have no idea what the `Transpose` equivalent can apply here!

P.S.: the values of the list do not matter, just the order of its elements I need changing.

Comment: Do you mean `a[[i]]` and `a[[i,j,k]]`?

Comment: sorry, yes! it is late here! i will correct the question now

Comment: `Transpose[a, {3, 1, 2}]`? or `Flatten[a, {{2}, {3}, {1}}]`?

Comment: @kglr which one is faster if the lists are large?

Comment: I got my answer! `Flatten` is about 5 times faster than Transpose! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ClearAll[a]
a = Array[x, {3, 2, 4}];

MatrixForm[a, TableDirections -> {Column, Row, Row}]
```

[image]

```
flattened = Flatten[a, {{2}, {3}, {1}}]

MatrixForm[flattened, TableDirections -> {Column, Row, Row}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

`Transpose` generalizes nicely to arbitrary levels! Try

```
Transpose[a, {3, 1, 2}]
```

The specification of `{3, 1, 2}` causes the first level in `a` (corresponding to the first position in the list `{3, 2, 1}`) to become the third level in the result, the second level to become the first, etc.; see the docs for more examples.

Comment: thank you for the answer! While this works, @kglr suggested a solution using `Flatten` which is about 5 times faster!

Comment: Nice! Surprising that Mathematica doesn't use that solution in the cases it can, then, tbh! :)

Answer (score 5):

Since the question is about performance, I think some timings should be included. There are two types of arrays and performance differs.  [Packed arrays](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array) are arrays whose elements are machine numbers of the same type.  Functions are optimized to leverage strengths of the CPU on such arrays. Unpacked arrays are essentially, I think, lists of pointers (to lists of pointers...) to expressions.

`Transpose` cannot be beat on packed arrays, I think:

```
aa = RandomReal[1, {300, 200, 400}];
flattened = Flatten[aa, {{2}, {3}, {1}}]; // RepeatedTiming
transposed = Transpose[aa, {3, 1, 2}]; // RepeatedTiming
(*
{0.431257, Null}
{0.0949386, Null}
*)
```

`Flatten` seems faster on unpacked arrays, but `Transpose` plus repacking the array is faster:

```
bb = Developer`FromPackedArray@aa;
flattened = Flatten[bb, {{2}, {3}, {1}}]; // RepeatedTiming
transposed = Transpose[bb, {3, 1, 2}]; // RepeatedTiming
repacked = Transpose[Developer`ToPackedArray@bb,
            {3, 1, 2}]; // RepeatedTiming
(*
{0.792751, Null}
{1.13911, Null}
{0.313727, Null}
*)
```

But `Transpose` barely (but consistently) beats `Flatten` on this unpacked array:

```
cc = Array[x, {50, 40, 100}];
flattened = Flatten[cc, {{2}, {3}, {1}}]; // RepeatedTiming
transposed = Transpose[cc, {3, 1, 2}]; // RepeatedTiming
(*
{0.0179923, Null}
{0.0153114, Null}
*)
```